# Read Parquet files from Scala without using Spark

Tags: scala

Is it possible to read parquet files from Scala without using Apache Spark?

I found a project which allows us to read and write avro files using plain scala.

https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s

However I can't find a way to read and write parquet files using plain scala program without using Spark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you don't have to use Spark to read/write Parquet. 
Just use parquet lib directly from your Scala code (and that's what Spark is doing anyway): http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cparquet

Comment: do you have any example on how to read parquet file using Parquet Lib, I cannot use parquet-mr project as it is not approved in my firm.

Answer (score 23):

It's straightforward enough to do using the [parquet-mr](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr) project, which is the project Alexey Raga is referring to in his answer.

Some sample code

```
val reader = AvroParquetReader.builder[GenericRecord](path).build().asInstanceOf[ParquetReader[GenericRecord]]
// iter is of type Iterator[GenericRecord]
val iter = Iterator.continually(reader.read).takeWhile(_ != null)
// if you want a list then...
val list = iter.toList
```

This will return you a standard Avro `GenericRecord`s, but if you want to turn that into a scala case class, then you can use my [Avro4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s) library as you linked to in your question, to do the marshalling for you. Assuming you are using version 1.30 or higher then:

```
case class Bibble(name: String, location: String)
val format = RecordFormat[Bibble]
// then for a given record
val bibble = format.from(record)
```

We can obviously combine that with the original iterator in one step:

```
val reader = AvroParquetReader.builder[GenericRecord](path).build().asInstanceOf[ParquetReader[GenericRecord]]
val format = RecordFormat[Bibble]
// iter is now an Iterator[Bibble]
val iter = Iterator.continually(reader.read).takeWhile(_ != null).map(format.from)
// and list is now a List[Bibble]
val list = iter.toList
```

Comment: Hi @monkjack thanks for your sample code, it is really helpful. Can you please provide a brief explanation about `builder[GenericRecord](path).build()` and `Iterator.continually(reader.read).takeWhile(_ != null).map(format.from)` I have started working on big data couple of months ago and the documentation of the above methods are really  hard for me to understand.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what to import exactly? For example "path" at the beginning of your code needs to be something that implements "InputFile"... what exactly is this and how exactly are we supposed to implement it?

Comment: Path in this case is a hadoop Path, so you need the hadoop libraries on your classpath.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for nested case classes. Anyone saw this working lately?

Answer (score 7):

There is also a relatively new project called [eel](https://github.com/eel-sdk/eel) this is a lightweight (non distributed processing) toolkit for using some of the 'big data' technology in the small.