# Using parquet-mr in Scala without Spark

Tags: java, scala, parquet

I'm trying to read a .parquet file in Scala without using Spark.

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235018/read-parquet-files-from-scala-without-using-spark), but so far have been unable to find how to use the [parquet-mr library](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr) to actually read from a file (including getting the schema). There are things like RecordReader.java and RecordReaderImplementation.java (which extends RecordReader), but I'm struggling to understand how to use these in my Scala code. I'm very new to Scala and the Parquet format, but would like to accomplish this without using Spark.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not finding anything else, I ended up building something myself. In case anyone else struggles with this in the future: https://github.com/jmd1011/parquet-readers

Comment: Ah, I see you commented here as well! Thank you for raising an issue on the repo, commenting on another issue on the repo, and downvoting both the question and answer here. Perhaps a more appropriate avenue to take in the future would be to simply ping me in one location and say, "Hey deckeresq, are you still working on this project? I'd love to get some docs/examples."

Comment: I did not downvote either one.  And I can prove that - by having now *upvoted* both.  SOF has a weird rule that you can not change your vote after 5 minutes - so if I *had* downvoted it would not have been possible to upvote. But I'm not upvoting to appease anyone (/you)  but because the Q&A are useful.  I was in a hurry at the time - thus my poor handling of the interactions and the lack of upvotes. Apologies for both.

Comment: @javadba Thanks for clarifying, and for letting me know. I definitely could've handled things better also! I'm currently swamped with other priorities for the next month or so, but I plan on adding docs and examples to the repo in question by the end of November.