# How to make a parquet file from a case class without using spark?

Tags: scala, parquet, playframework-2.4

I know that we can make a parquet file from dataframe. Now suppose that, we have a class class like below:

```
case class Person(
        id:   String,
        name: String,
        roll: Option[Int]
  )
```

Now, we have Seq[**Person**] and i want to make a parquet file from this sequence of person. In this case, we won't use spark.

So, How can we make a parquet file using scala/play from Seq[**Person**]?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use `parquet-mr`module. Here's I think a Java example https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetOutputFormat.java

Comment: Also => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754062/using-parquet-mr-in-scala-without-spark

Comment: How to do it using scala? Is there any scala code for parquet-mr module?