# How to use ParquetReader with path containing other directories?

Tags: apache, hadoop, avro, parquet

I have a hdfs path structure like this: _P_ROOT=foo/_P_A=4444/_P_B=1/_P_C=20, where all my parquet files sits under _P_C. *P* is a partition.

With Spark I am able to specify a path up to any level, e.g.: only _P_ROOT, _P_A, or _P_B. 
e.g.: 
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("_P_ROOT=foo/") 
and my df will have other directories as columns.

Now, I have like to read parquet without Spark.

I am using AvroParquetReader thanks to [Read Parquet files from Scala without using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235018/read-parquet-files-from-scala-without-using-spark)

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
val reader = AvroParquetReader
  .builder[GenericRecord](path)
  .build()
  .asInstanceOf[ParquetReader[GenericRecord]]

val iter: Iterator[GenericRecord] = Iterator
   .continually(reader.read)
   .takeWhile(_ != null)
```

This works if my path is all the way up to _P_C. However, if I specify a path that contains other directories, I will get an empty iterator.

So my question is: 
How can I specify a path to read parquet when the path is not a leaf directory. Without Spark of course.