# Scala: How can I return Option[Dataframe] of parquet file(which is in adls) - without using spark/sql session

Tags: scala

The following link could be the hint but it would be nice to see some example code which does that

[Read Parquet files from Scala without using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235018/read-parquet-files-from-scala-without-using-spark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `DataFrame` is one of Spark's *distributed* data collections; Spark's one and only way for creating distributed collections is through a valid `SparkSession`. You can't create a `DataFrame` without it.

The link you provided shows how to load Parquet files into non-distributed collections, not into a `DataFrame`.

The simplest type of a `SparkSession` is a *local* one, where all of Spark's components actually run in-process. That means that this session doesn't require any setup of configuration (no existing Spark processes running or installed anywhere). This is helpful mostly for tests but might be helpful for your usecase. Here's how you create one:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate
```