# Read Parquet into scala without Spark

Tags: scala, parquet

I have a Parquet file which I would like to read into my Scala program without using Spark or other Big Data Technologies.

I found the projects

- https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr
- https://github.com/51zero/eel-sdk

but not detailed enough examples to get them to work.

## Parquet-MR

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35594368/4533188 mentions this, but the examples given are not complete. For example it is not clear what `path` is supposed to be. It is supposed to implement `InputFile`, how is this supposed to be done? Also, from the post it seems to me that Parquet-MR does not directly truns the parquet data as standard Scala classes.

## Eel

Here I tried

import io.eels.component.parquet.ParquetSource
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

```
val parquetFilePath = new Path("file://home/raeg/Datatroniq/Projekte/14. Witzenmann/Teilprojekt Strom und Spannung/python_witzenmann/src/data/1.parquet")
implicit val hadoopConfiguration = new Configuration()
implicit val hadoopFileSystem = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration) // This is required

ParquetSource(parquetFilePath)
  .toDataStream()
  .collect
  .foreach(row => println(row))
```

but I get the error

```
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: file
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(ParquetReaderTesting.sc:2582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(ParquetReaderTesting.sc:2589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(ParquetReaderTesting.sc:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(ParquetReaderTesting.sc:2628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(ParquetReaderTesting.sc:2610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(ParquetReaderTesting.sc:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(ParquetReaderTesting.sc:165)
    at dataReading.A$A6$A$A6.hadoopFileSystem$lzycompute(ParquetReaderTesting.sc:7)
    at dataReading.A$A6$A$A6.hadoopFileSystem(ParquetReaderTesting.sc:7)
    at dataReading.A$A6$A$A6.get$$instance$$hadoopFileSystem(ParquetReaderTesting.sc:7)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(ParquetReaderTesting.sc:30)
```

in my worksheet.